# Is there a way to hide the scroll indicators of ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I want to use the entire width of the screen and be able to make it scrollable. 
 So I want to hide the scroll indicator of a `ScrollView`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did u tried this: `scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
scrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a `ScrollView` *without* scroll bars, you can use the following:

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

You can do it porgramatically as follows:

```
yourScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
yourScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Edit: Can you try this one `android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"`

Comment: Some time its not working

Answer (score 0):

In layout file set `scrollbars="none"`

Answer (score 0):

try this: Programmatically set

```
 scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
 scrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Or

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```